# Issue while doing in-AppPurchase in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am adding in-`AppPurchase` feature to my app.

I want to select the type as `non-consumable` but I am not getting that option.

I am getting this screen. Anyone knows how to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Have you completed all of the necessary paperwork in the tax and banking module?

Comment: @Paulw11 i am doing it first time..what i have to in tax and banking module

Answer (score 0):

It seems you or the agent of your account haven't agree the latest Paid Application agreement.

> You must have a Paid Applications contract with Apple in place to use IAP.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html

Answer (score 0):

You haven't requested paid application contract. Go to `Managing Agreements, Tax, and Banking` section from your itunes accounts and request for the specific. Once you requested those contract you will have the options, but it may take some time before apple verified your contract and after that you will be able to test with the specific `product id`